# Reset formula numbering in ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering, context

I am writing exercises and their detailled answers, and I'd like to reset the formula numbering between each exercise. Is it even possible? If it is, how can it be done? I can't find anything like this in the manual or on the wiki...

## EDIT 2

I know I can use the `bysection` option, but the point is that I don't use sections in order to label exercise titles : I already use them for the lesson itself. The structure of my document is the following (I use conditionnal processing a lot to create documents with only questions, questions and answers, hints, with or without the lesson etc...)

I finally found time to post a proper MWE. I tested it in a separate directory.

```
\enablemode[lesson]

\starttext

%% The lesson itself
\startmode[lesson]
   \section{Bla}

   ...

\stopmode

%% The exercises
\def\exs{
  \exercisepath[/home/adrien/dev/test]  %% to be adapted
  \inputexercise[exercise_file]
  \inputexercise[exercise_file2]
}

\hairline
\enablemode[exercise]
\exs
\disablemode[exercise]

\hairline
\enablemode[answers]
\exs
\disablemode[answers]

\stoptext
```

and each file `exercise_file` has the following structure :

```
\exercisetitle[The title]

\startmode[exercise]
  questions
\stopmode

\startmode[answers]
  detailed answers

  \placeformula[eq:test]
  \startformula
    a = b
  \stopformula

  The eq is \eqref[eq:test]

\stopmode
```

The personnal commands are the following (defined in an environment file, can be pasted before the `starttext` for testing purposes) :

```
%% eq ref
\definereferenceformat[eqref][left={$(},right={)$}]

%% manage the exercise files directories 
\unprotect
\def\exercisepath[#1]{
  \gdef\@exercisepath{#1}
  \setupexternalfigures[directory={#1}]
}
\def\inputexercise[#1]{
  \ReadFile{\@exercisepath/#1}\flushsidefloats
}   
\protect

%% format the exercise title with a possible precision (eg the difficulty) 
\def\doExercisetitle[#1][#2]{
  \blank\noindenting
  {\hskip 1cm \bs #1
    \ifsecondargument \\ \tf \it [#2] \fi
  }
  \blank[small,samepage]
}

\def\exercisetitle{\dodoubleempty\doExercisetitle}
```

I would like each exercise file to be "independant" regarding the formula numbering. Is this possible ?

Comment: When you normal section levels for each exercise you can reset the formula counter with each new exercise, e.g. `\setupformulas[way=bysection]`. For a better answer you have to show us a example of your document.

Comment: You can reset the value of the formula counter with `\resetcounter[formula]`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you post this as an answer ? I could mark it as accepted. As a side question, how can I find the list (and names) of counters defined in ConTeXt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to use the `\resetcounter` command to reset the value of a given counter, e.g. `\resetcounter[formula]` to reset the `formula` number.

```
\usemodule[visual]

\setuppapersize[A5]

\startbuffer[formula]
    \startplaceformula
        \startformula
            \fakeformula
        \stopformula
    \stopplaceformula
\stopbuffer

\starttext

\dorecurse{3}{\getbuffer[formula]}

\blank[2*line] \resetcounter[formula]

\dorecurse{3}{\getbuffer[formula]}

\stoptext
```

[image: Manual reset of the formula counter]

The better solution is to create a new `section` for the exercises and reset the `formula` counter with the start of each exercise. To reset the counter with each new exercise you pass the name of the section as argument to the `way` key in `\setupformula`.

```
\usemodule[visual]

\setuppapersize[A5]

\definehspace [exercise] [1cm]

\definehead [exercisetitle] [subject]

\define[2]\ExerciseTitleCommand
  {\vbox\bgroup
     \dontleavehmode\hspace[exercise]\structuretitle
     \doifsomething{\structureuservariable{subtitle}}
       {\par{\tf\it[\structureuservariable{subtitle}]}}%
   \egroup}

\setuphead
  [exercisetitle]
  [command=\ExerciseTitleCommand,
   style=boldslanted]

\startbuffer[formula]
    \startplaceformula
        \startformula
            \fakeformula
        \stopformula
    \stopplaceformula
\stopbuffer

% \setupformula
%   [way=bysection]

\setupformula
  [way=byexercisetitle]

\starttext

\startexercisetitle [title={First exercise}]
    \dorecurse{3}{\getbuffer[formula]}
\stopexercisetitle

\startexercisetitle [title={Second exercise}] [subtitle={Counter reset}]
    \dorecurse{3}{\getbuffer[formula]}
\stopexercisetitle

\stoptext
```

[image: Automatic reset of the formula counter]